# jQuery: Call function after ajax has completely rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I am using a function `pinterest_it()` to adjust a view with [masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and I'm using another function `recipeLoader()` to show a loading icon until the page completely loads, then display content.  This works on page refresh, but when I load content using ajax, my `$( window ).load(...)` function never fires.

**How can make the function call after everything completely loads (not .ready)**

```
function pinterest_it() {
    $(".loader").show(); # shows loading icon
    $("#recipe-index").css("opacity", 0); # makes content invisible

    if ( $(document).innerWidth() < 991 ) {
        gutter = 0
    } else {
        gutter = 16
    }

    var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {

        var $blah = $('.grid').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
                return $('.grid-sizer').width();
            },
            percentPosition: true,
            gutterWidth: gutter
        });

    }, fixGrid())

    recipeLoader(); # see below
}

function recipeLoader() {
    console.log("recipe loader")
    $(window).load(function() { # doesn't fire after Ajax completes!
        console.log("loaded")
        $(".loader").hide(); # hides loading icon
        $("#recipe-index").animate({
            opacity: 1 # shows content
        }, 400);
    });
}

# one of the Ajax function that calls pinterest_it()
$(".togglebutton input").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).serialize());
    $.get(this.action, $('#recipes_search').serialize(), function() {
        pinterest_it();
    }, 'script')
});
```

I've tried `$(x).ready(...)` with no luck, as well as `ajaxComplete()`.  Perhaps there is some way to use `$(x).load(...)` with a specific element rather than window to allow the function to fire?  I've tried calling it on `$("#recipe-index")` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score -2):

$(window).load doesn't fire on success/completion of an Ajax request. Move that bit to its own function:

```
  function handlePageRefresh () {
    console.log("loaded")
    $(".loader").hide(); # hides loading icon
    $("#recipe-index").animate({
        opacity: 1 # shows content
    }, 400);
 }
```

And then call it in $(window).load & the Ajax success callback

```
$(window).load(function() { # doesn't fire after Ajax completes!
    handlePageRefresh()
});

# one of the Ajax function that calls pinterest_it()
$(".togglebutton input").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).serialize());
    $.get(this.action, $('#recipes_search').serialize(), function() {
      handlePageRefresh()
      pinterest_it();
    }, 'script')
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't work because there is a delay between when the function call is complete and when the window is fully loaded.

Comment: Looking at my console, I can see there is a completed 200 request.  When that is completed, I want to call my function (in your case, handlePageRefresh())